# How can we inherit UITableViewDataSource protocol in our class?

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

[image]

I want to use table view in my application. But when i confirm my view controller to UITableViewDataSource, it gives error shown in image. How to use UITableViewDataSource protocol in our class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not the proper way to specify protocol conformance. This is the proper syntax.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    // stuff
}
```

If you're still seeing that error, it's because your class doesn't implement the required methods from these delegates, in this case, numberOfRowsInSection.... and cellForRowAtIndexPath....

Comment: @Rahul That's for a different reason. What I've shown you is the correct way to make your class conform the the protocol, but now, you're seeing that error because your class doesn't implement the required methods from these delegates, in this case, numberOfRowsInSection.... and cellForRowAtIndexPath....

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But first we inherit protocol after that we can use methods. Before confirming to protocol can you have access to delegate method?

Comment: @Rahul Not through auto-complete, no.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to use class extensions for conforming a protocol, that kind of isolation makes your code more maintainable later when your class has grown up, like e.g.:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

   // ...

}
```

and you can extend it with the protocols

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
        return nil
    }

    // ... 

}
```

and

```
extension MainViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

    // ...

}
```

Comment: But in this case where should I set tableview.delegate = self?

Comment: it depends where you have declared your outlet at.